# React container's props changes causing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, callback, react-redux, react-props

I have a container which has access to the Redux state and maps a certain pieces of that state to its props, the piece I'm interested in is 'coins' so

> this.props.coins

Using console.log() I can see that when rendering the container I have access to that piece of state.

This container houses one component that receives a callback function and this previously mentioned piece of state, coins, via its own props in

> onClickHandler() && coinData

The container has a function to handle the callback called

> _handleClick()

In this function for some reason this.props doesn't give access to the same coins I was able to access in the render function but has access to the props that I'm passing to the component, props I thought would belong to the component. So from _handleClick() in the container I have access to

> this.props.onClickHandler() && this.props.coinData

but not

> this.props.coins

which is what I was expecting to have access to from anywhere within my container. I get the error in the title of the post when I try to access this.props.coins in my callback handler _handleClick() but why is that and why do I have access to the props that should belong to the corresponding child component? Is there any way that I can access this.props.coins from the _handleClick() call?

My container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ChartSelectMenu from '../components/ChartSelectMenu';
import { selectCoinForChart } from '../actions/index';

class ChartSelectMenuContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  _handleClick(ticker) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked: ", ticker);
    console.log("coin_list: ", this.props);

    const coin_list = this.props.coins;
    //
    for (let i=0; i<coin_list.length; i++) {
      if (coin_list[i].ticker === ticker) {
        this.props.dispatch(selectCoinForChart(ticker));
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Container props on render(): ", this.props);
      return (
        <ChartSelectMenu
        onClickHandler={this._handleClick}
        coinData={this.props.coins}
        />
      );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ auth, coins, selectedCoin }) {
  return { auth, coins, selectedCoin };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChartSelectMenuContainer);
```

It's component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const style = {
  display: 'inline-block',
  margin: '16px 0px 16px 0px',
};

class ChartSelectMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    }

  _renderMenuItems() {
    if (this.props === null) {
      return <h3>Loading...</h3>;
    } else {
      return(this.props.coinData.map((coin) => {
        return <MenuItem
          key={coin.ticker}
          onClick={this.props.onClickHandler.bind(this, coin.ticker)}
          primaryText={coin.ticker}
        />
      }));
    }
  }
  render() {
    //console.log('ChartSelectMenu props: ', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <Paper style={style}>
          <Menu>
            <ul>
              {this._renderMenuItems()}
            </ul>
          </Menu>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ChartSelectMenu;
```

Comment: Make handle click as an arrow function..or use var self = this inside your  function

Answer (score 0):

When @MukulSharma commented 'use var self = this inside your function' I thought to try to bind the _handleClick function in the constructor of the container and it worked.

The solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ChartSelectMenu from '../components/ChartSelectMenu';
import { selectCoinForChart } from '../actions/index';


class ChartSelectMenuContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  _handleClick(ticker) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked: ", ticker);
    console.log("coin_list: ", this.props);

    const coin_list = this.props.coins;
    //
    for (let i=0; i<coin_list.length; i++) {
      if (coin_list[i].ticker === ticker) {
        this.props.dispatch(selectCoinForChart(ticker));
      }
    }
  }

  render() { ...
```